# Changing color for specific amount of time java

Tags: java

How do I make a FilledOval change color for only half a second and then change back to its original color in java?

```
  if(target.contains(shooter.getLocation())){         
     target.setColor(Color.RED);       
  }
```

Trying to make it change to red only for half a second and then back to black.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is a Swing GUI: Use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). Set the color as you're doing above, and then start a Swing Timer that does not repeat, i.e., that calls `setRepeats(false)`, and within the Timer's ActionListener, return the color back to baseline, and then call `start()` on the Timer.

i.e.,

```
if(target.contains(shooter.getLocation())) {         
    target.setColor(Color.RED);
    int mSecs = 500;
    Timer timer = new Timer(mSecs, new TimerListener(target));
    timer.setRepeats(false);
    timer.start();
}
```

I'll leave the code for TimerListener up to you, but I've described above what it must do.

Comment: How can I prevent it from changing colors for a second after it changes to red?

Comment: @E.Sapetnitzky: that's a new and different problem and will depend on much that you've not told us.

Comment: You missed a `)` after the `Timer` declaration.